# What is causing my "illegal character in input string" exception with Facebook PHP SDK when deploying to Heroku?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, heroku, laravel-4

"facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "4.0.*" - resolves to 4.0.15
Javascript SDK v2.2

I'm having an issue when deploying my laravel app to Heroku using the latest JS SDK and PHP SDK.

It works perfectly locally (nginx) but when deployed to Heroku (Apache) it fails here:
$helper = new FacebookJavaScriptLoginHelper();
with exception - 
iconv_strlen(): Detected an illegal character in input string

Logs with both local and remote cookies look the same (structurally), so it's not that:

[fbsr_75710##########] => dJPP8B2GrKYHLmM8826lLXsjclHexnHv4V-dooUISI0.eyJhbGdvcml0aG0iOiJITUFDLVNIQTI...........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. If you look at the full stack trace you will see that `mb_strlen` is used before `iconv` and returns a bad result; turns out that on Heroku, the `mbstring` extension [is not enabled by default](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#extensions). You need to manually request it in your composer.json, in the `"require":` bit:

```
"ext-mbstring": "*"
```

Update, push and it should work for you. Bit of a late answer but hopefully this will be helpful for anyone running into the same issue.